# Where is the mailing template for the automated membership renewal reminder

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

we have an email set to be sent out to members as a reminder for membership renewal 6 weeks prior to the end date of membership. I am trying to locate a specific template, as it needs the signature updated and, more importantly, has some broken links, as we've upgraded some forms on our public site. I have looked under Mailing Templates, Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages, as well as anywhere else i can think of but cannot locate the email.

Any assistance locating the automatic email would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Saba
SSaleem@nonprofitoregon.org

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can find it in Schedule Reminders. Go to Administer -> Communications -> Schedule Reminders or use `http://<server>/civicrm/admin/scheduleReminders?reset=1`